# Rails: Wrap parameter coming from form in a nested hash

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have the following form for search which should also perform filtering:

```
<%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get, id: 'search_form' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'filter param', 'yes', true %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

What i'm trying to do now is to wrap parameters for filtering in a nested hash so that I have something as follows in params: `{"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"term", "action"=>"index", "controller"=>"search", "filter" => {"field" => "value"}}`. Note that filter params are nested

I couldn't find a way to do this using standard rails form helpers. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `[]` around the nested keys that you want.  In your example, change your check_box to:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'filter[field]', 'value', true %>
```

If you wanted something in the form:

```
{ "filter" => { "subfilter" => { "field" => "value" } } }
```

You would add another `[]`:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'filter[subfilter][field]', 'value', true %>
```